Solving irrational equations over the field of complex numbers
Do irrational equations like
$$x + \sqrt{x − 1} = 7$$
have solutions over the field of complex numbers and which definition(s) of the complex $n$th root should we use to obtain solutions to such equations?

I propose the following approach:
$$x + \sqrt{x − 1} = 7$$
By letting $\sqrt{x − 1} = y$ we get a system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
x + y = 7 \\
y^2 = x - 1
\end{cases}$$
which leads to a quadratic equation
$$x^2 − 15x + 50 = 0$$
with the solutions $x = 5$ and $x = 10$.
For $x = 5$ we have $y = 2$, i.e. the value of the radical $\sqrt{x − 1}$ should be taken to be equal to $2$.
For $x = 10$ we have $y = −3$, i.e. the value of the radical should be taken to be equal to $-3$.
I use the following definition:

A solution of an irrational equation $f(x, y, ..., z) = 0$ over the field of complex numbers is a system of values of unknowns for which at least one of the values of the irrational expression $f(x, y, ..., z)$ is equal to zero.

Thus, under this definition, an equation $f(x, y, ..., z) = 0$ is generalized here to an inclusion $f(x, y, ..., z) \ni 0$.
